# What is Maximum Length for a XSL variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, watson

I am working on a tool called Velocity(Now IBM Watson Data Explorer) which uses XSLT as a programming language to write converters to extract data, I have a situation where I am using one XSL variable to hold so many values(comma-separated). 
because of this Converter is not able to crawl data from the XML file.
I guess it's failing because of a variable holding so much data.

*Sample of XML:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atom:feed xmlns:atom=" " xmlns:wplc=" " xmlns:age=" ">
<atom:entry xml:lang="en">
        <atom:id>0111111111</atom:id>
        <atom:link href=""/>
        <atom:content src=""/>
        <wplc:securityId></wplc:securityId>
        <atom:author>
            <atom:name>2058281</atom:name>
            <atom:email>abc@gmail.com</atom:email>
        </atom:author>
        <atom:category term="Support" scheme="" label="Support"/>
        <atom:title xml:lang="en">General Report</atom:title>
        <wplc:field id="Role">abc-11,def-103,fgh-31,ijk-111,lmn-91</wplc:field>
        <wplc:field id="Country">N/A</wplc:field>
        <atom:published>2017-03-02T15:35:48-05:00</atom:published>
        <wplc:field id="Store">100,1000,1001,1002</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>

<atom:entry xml:lang="en">
</atom:entry>

<atom:entry xml:lang="en">
</atom:entry>

<atom:entry xml:lang="en">
</atom:entry>

</atom:feed>
```

AS per the requirement we need to create a variable which will have combination of Roles and Stores(each role will be associated with all the Stores).

**Ex :abc-11-1000 abc-11-1001 abc-11-1002 def-103-1000 def-103-1001..so on**.
In one case we have 220 roles(comma-separated) and 1000 stores(comma-separated).

Currently I am using two `<xsl:for-each>` (outer and inner) loops to create that variable, if values are limited then it working fine but in this particular case it's failing, where combination of roles and stores is huge.

**NOTE: i am not using an individual XSL parser, it's part of a tool called Velocity (Enterprise search Engine). so it could a tool limitation.**

but is there any better way to handle this problem using XSLT?

Comment: why not use a set of nodes instead of a comma seperated string?

Comment: would need to see xml and xslt to give better answer

Comment: How exactly is it failing? There is no limit defined in the spec, it depends on the XSLT processor implementation. If it's written in Java I wouldn't expect to see a limit less than 2Gb, and it will probably grind to a halt through lack of resources before it hits a hard limit.

Comment: I have edited my question and added a sample XML.